# XML Schema for sequence of elements with same name but different attribute values?

Tags: xml, xsd

How can I specify an XML schema for an instance document like this:

```
<productinfo>
  <!-- other stuff -->
  <informationset type="Manufacturer">
    <!-- content not relevant -->
  </informationset>
  <informationset type="Ingredients">
    <!-- content not relevant -->
  </informationset>
</productinfo>
```

that is, a "productinfo" element containing a sequence of two "informationset" children, the first having `@type="Manufacturer"` and the second having `@type="Ingredients"`?

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE** this answer is incorrect, as Serge pointed out.

Testing with *xerces* gives this error: `type.xsd:3:21: cos-element-consistent: Error for type '#AnonType_productinfo'. Multiple elements with name 'informationset', with different types, appear in the model group.` There's more detail in the spec for [cos-element-consistent](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#cos-element-consistent).

But there's a solution, similar to Marc's answer below, but still using types. It is possible to have multiple occurrences of the same with different types, if they are in a minOccurs/maxOccurs list of a supertype, which is extended by the other types.  That is, just like a list of polymorphic classes in java or C#. This overcomes the problem above because although that element name can appear many times in the xml, it only appears once in the xsd.

Here is example xsd and xml - tested with *xerces* this time!:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="productinfo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="informationset" type="supertype" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="supertype">
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Manufacturer">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="supertype">
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Ingredients">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="supertype">
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>

<productinfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <informationset xsi:type="Manufacturer"></informationset>
  <informationset xsi:type="Ingredients"></informationset>
</productinfo>
```

NOTE: You can't control the *order* of the different types, or how many times each type occurs (each could appear once, many times, or not appear at all) - just as with  a list of polymorphic classes in java or C#.  But you can at least specify at exact length of the list overall (if you like).

For example, I've restricted the above example to exactly two elements, but the order is not set (i.e. *Manufacturer* could be first, or *Ingredients* could be first); and number of repetitions is not set (i.e. they could both be *Manufacturer*, or both *Ingredients*, or one of each).

---

You can, with XML Schema *type*, as in:

```
<productinfo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <informationset xsi:type="Manufacturer"></informationset>
  <informationset xsi:type="Ingredients"></informationset>
</productinfo>
```

And the XSD defines separate complex types for each one:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="productinfo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="informationset" type="Manufacturer"/>
        <xs:element name="informationset" type="Ingredients"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="Manufacturer">
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Ingredients">
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

This is a special case for `xsi:type`.  In general, don't think you can specify attributes to have different values in elements of the same name, because they are different definitions of the same element.

I'm not 100% clear on the precise reason - anyone know the relevant part of the spec?

Comment: If I open the xsd you provided, I get "Elements with the same name and in the same scope must have the same type" error...

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for checking and responding. I originally tested the above only with `xmllint` (which accepts it); but testing with the more rigorous `xerces` gives a similar error to what you got: `type.xsd:3:21: cos-element-consistent: Error for type '#AnonType_productinfo'. Multiple elements with name 'informationset', with different types, appear in the model group.` Looking this up in the spec give more detail http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-xmlschema-1-20041028/structures.html#cos-element-consistent

Comment: It's odd that I up-vote an incorrect answer, but the comment with the "Elements with the same name and in the same scope..." message got me here with a search.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this - create a separate complexType for your "informationSet" elements, and limit the attribute to a list of valid strings:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="productinfo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" 
                    name="informationset" type="informationSetType" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="informationSetType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="type" type="validAttributeType" use="required" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:simpleType name="validAttributeType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Manufacturer" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Ingredients" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Of course, you can extend that list of valid attribute names if you wish - just add more elements to the restriction-enumeration list there.

Marc

Answer (score 1):

#### Using Assertion Schema Component

Thanks to **XML Schema 1.1**, there is a way to enforce your requirement without having to import the `xsi` namespace and hack polymorphism into your XML document. XML Schema 1.1 brought two new components, [**assertions**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions) and [**type alternatives**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative), providing the `xs:assert` and `xs:alternative` elements. They have a `@test` attribute in which conditions and constraints are being specified as **XPath 2.0 expressions**.

---

Even though `xs:alternative` is obviously meant to be the solution to your problem, I for my part have not yet succeeded in assigning alternative types based on an element's position. (*The schema parser's understanding of node contexts seems to differ from the one I would expect based on the validated XML document structure.*)

---

**Anyway**, you can enforce your constraints using `xs:assert`:

```
<xs:element name="productinfo">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="informationset">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:attribute name="type" use="required">
            <xs:simpleType>
              <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="Manufacturer" />
                <xs:enumeration value="Ingredients" />
              </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
          </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:assert test="informationset[1]/@type='Manufacturer'" xpathDefaultNamespace="##targetNamespace"/>
    <xs:assert test="informationset[2]/@type='Ingredients'" xpathDefaultNamespace="##targetNamespace"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The use of attribute `@xpathDefaultNamespace` may not be necessary if your schema's namespace is null, but *must* be set to `##targetNamespace` if you schema defines one, otherwise evaluation of the element name will fail.

> **Note:** Obviously, for this to work it is necessary to use a validator which supports XML Schema 1.1. When using, say, OxygenXML, you can just set the default XML schema version to 1.1 in the *XML / XML Parser / XML Schema* preference page. When using Xerces as a validator, an [additional feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25191506/1933494) must be activated: `http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/cta-full-xpath-checking`. Otherwise it will fail to evaluate most of the XPath you come up with because it uses an insufficient subset by default.

---

Answer (score 0):

May be that http://xsd.stylusstudio.com/2001Aug/post03013.htm is what you are looking for.

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.

Answer (score 0):

In VS, reports an error: **Elements with the same name and in the same scope must have the same type.** 
I think XSD can't fullfill your requirement, you can try to solve it from another direction.for example, use xslt to validate XML. XSLT is xpath based and rule based, it can check every places in xml.
XSD + XSLT is a good solution, XSD for schema check, XSLT for information check.