# XSD 1.1 Conditional Type Assignment <alternative test=""> to check if an element hasn't an attribute set?

Tags: xml, xpath, xsd-validation, xsd-1.1

I would like to ask if someone knows how to make an  XSD 1.1 Conditional Type Assignment check if an element hasn't an attribute using the XPath query, e.g.:

```
<!--inline alternative type definitions --> 
<element name="TimeTravel" type="TravelType"> 
      <alternative test="@direction='Future'"> 
          <complexType> 
              <complexContent> 
              <restriction base="TravelType" 
                         .... 
<!--        some past travel related elements go here --> 
            </complexType> 
       </alternative> 
      <alternative test="@direction='Past'"> 
          <complexType> 
              <complexContent> 
              <restriction base="TravelType" 
                         .... 
   <!--        some future travel related elements go here --> 
            </complexType> 
       </alternative> 
  </element> 
                          OR 
<!--Named alternative type definitions --> 
<element name="TimeTravel" type="TravelType"> 
   <alternative test="@direction='Future' type="FutureTravelType"/> 
   <alternative test="@direction='Past' type="PastTravelType"/> 
</element>
```

In this example the 'alternative test=""' checks whether the attribute "direction" of the TimeTravel element has a value of "Future" or "Past". How should I write the XPath query to check if e.g. there's no "direction" attribute for the current element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The XPath `"@direction"` will test for the **presence** of a `direction` attribute on the current element:

```
<alternative test="@direction" type="DirectionType"/>
```

The XPath `"not(@direction)"` will test for the **absence** of a `direction` attribute on the current element:

```
<alternative test="not(@direction)" type="NoDirectionType"/>
```

Note also that the `alternative/@test` attribute can be omitted altogether to provide a **default** type.

```
<alternative type="DefaultType"/>
```

### Update to address CTA subset mode per OP's follow-up question

> So this `<alternative test="@direction='a_value' and not(@another_attribute)"/>` is correct and would make it right?

Yes, but be aware that your XSD processor may use the XPath CTA ([**Conditional Type Assignment**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative)) subset by default.  (Xerces, and therefore most Xerces-based tools, do this, for example.)  If this is the case, you will get an error that looks something like this:

> c-cta-xpath: The XPath expression 'not(@direction)' couldn't compile
>   successfully in 'cta-subset' mode, during CTA evaluation.
>
> c-cta-xpath: The XPath expression '@direction='a_value' and
>   not(@another_attribute)' couldn't compile successfully in 'cta-subset'
>   mode, during CTA evaluation.

To use full XPath 2.0 rather than the CTA subset, configure your tool accordingly.  For example, for Xerces, set the following feature to 'true':

```
http://apache.org/xml/features/validation/cta-full-xpath-checking
```

In oXygen, there's a checkbox in `Options > Preferences > XML > XML Parser > XML Schema` that will control the value of the feature for you.

**Using full XPath 2.0, yes, you can use `and` in the manner you suggest in your comment.**

Comment: Thank you for your explanatory response, just another question, if for example I need to check that the element has an attribute with a particular value and at the same time check if another attribute is absent what can I do?

Comment: You can use [**boolean expressions**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans) to build up more complicated conditions using `and`, `or`, and `not`.

Comment: Thanks for the link! So this `<alternative test="@direction='a_value' and not(@another_attribute)">` is correct and would make it right?

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance, but what does CTA mean in XPath CTA? Surfed the net but didn't find anything.

Comment: **CTA** is [**Conditional Type Assignment**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative).